# Does ''bang" mean "suddenly and out of control" in the mentioned sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does ''bang" mean "suddenly and out of control" in this sentence?

> You have no control over it; you see the photo and, **bang**, the picture
>   forms in your mind.

Answer (score 2):

It has the meaning of **suddenly, surprisingly, unexpectedly.** To the extent that what you control is not likely to surprise you, there may be some implication that **you** are not in control of whatever is being discussed. (If what is being discussed is your own mental state, then what is implicated is a lack of conscious control.) But the primary meaning is **sudden** or **unexpected**.

But typically something described as being *out of control** is dangerous, or at least unwelcome, because it is outside its normal constraints. We would not usually say that a river flowing between its banks is out of control even though no human controls its flow, but we might well say that a river flooding beyond its banks is **out of control**.

Answer (score 1):

The word *bang* is [**onomatopoeia**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia), which is a term used to refer to words that resembles a particular sound – in this case, the sound of a gunshot or explosion. Other example of  onomatopoeia include words such as *whirr*, *buzz* and *moo*.

In the context you gave, though, the word *bang*  not referring to a loud physical explosion per se, but to the **suddenness** of an unexpected explosion. The writer is explaining how an idea comes into the mind, not gradually, but very suddenly and all at once.

[image]